# How do I read a file in an async function without promises?

Tags: javascript, file, fs, read-write

I'm trying to read/write to a file in an async function (example):

```
async readWrite() {
      // Create a variable representing the path to a .txt
      const file = 'file.txt';

      // Write "test" to the file
      fs.writeFileAsync(file, 'test');
      // Log the contents to console
      console.log(fs.readFileAsync(file));
}
```

But whenever I run it I always get the error:

```
(node:13480) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 2): TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of null
```

I tried using bluebird by installing it using `npm install bluebird` in my project directory and adding:

```
const Bluebird = require('bluebird');
const fs = Bluebird.promisifyAll(require('fs'));
```

to my `index.js` (main) file, as well as adding:

```
const fs = require('fs');
```

to every file where I wan't to use fs.

I still get the same error and can only narrow down the problem to fs through commenting out stuff.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Am I getting this right? You don't want to use promises, but you're using bluebird?

Comment: bluebird is a promise library.

Answer (score 4):

First of all: `async` `function`s return a promise. So by definition, you are already using a promise.

Second, there is no `fs.writeFileAsync`. You are looking for `fs.writeFile` https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefile_file_data_options_callback

## With promises, making use of the power of async functions

```
const fs = require('fs');
const util = require('util');

// Promisify the fs.writeFile and fs.readFile
const write = util.promisify(fs.writeFile);
const read = util.promisify(fs.readFile);

async readWrite() {
  // Create a variable representing the path to a .txt
  const file = 'file.txt';

  // Write "test" to the file
  await write(file, 'test');
  // Log the contents to console
  const contents = await read(file, 'utf8');
  console.log(contents);
}
```

In the above: We used [util.promisify](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original) to turn the nodejs callback style using functions to promises. Inside an async function, you can use the [await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) keyword to store the resolved contents of a promise to a const/let/var.

Further reading material: https://ponyfoo.com/articles/understanding-javascript-async-await

## Without promises, callback-style

```
const fs = require('fs');
async readWrite() {
  // Create a variable representing the path to a .txt
  const file = 'file.txt';

  // Write "test" to the file
  fs.writeFile(file, 'test', err => {
    if (!err) fs.readFile(file, 'utf8', (err, contents)=> {
      console.log(contents);
    })
  });
}
```